# use array to change every digit in a 3-digit number

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n,d1,d2,d3;
cout<<"Enter a 3-digit positive integer"<<endl;
cin>>n;
d1=n/100;
d2=n%100/10;
d3=n%10;
int a[3]{d1,d2,d3};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if(a[i]!=0){
        a[i]=10-a[i];
    }
    cout<<"The new number is :"<<a[i]<<endl;
}
```

}

This code takes a 3-digit integer as input and returns a new number in which all non-zero digits in the original are replaced by the distance between the digit and 10, for example, if one of the digits is 2 so the new digit will be 10-2=8. But the problem is with the output.
[image]

I want the program to print (The new number is :(here the new digits in the same line)), instead of repeating the message and printing each digit in a separate line. How can I do that??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: u can print the information out from the for  loop
or u can do
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if(a[i]!=0){
        a[i]=10-a[i];
    }
if(i ==0)
    cout<<"The new number is :";
cout <<a[i];
}
cout << endl;

Comment: Your code first deconstructs `n` to obtain elements of the array.   You need to write code that reconstructs an integral value from elements of the array.   Incidentally, if any of the digits are `5` OR `0`, that digit will not be changed.

Comment: @alon thank you so much I used it and now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can print the information out from the for loop or u can do for loop like this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if(a[i]!=0){
        a[i]=10-a[i];
    }
    if(i == 0)
    cout<<"The new number is :";
    cout <<a[i];
}

    cout << endl
```

Answer (score 1):

This for loop,

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if(a[i]!=0){
        a[i]=10-a[i];
    }
    cout<<"The new number is :"<<a[i]<<endl;
}
```

Is the issue for your problem. This means that your printing `The new number is :` on every iteration. What we need to do is, print it once and print all the integers after it. Its very simple, just change the position of the `std::cout` to be before the for loop and we can put in a little optimization; we dont need to store the `10 - a[i]`, we can directly print it.

```cpp
cout << "The new number is : ";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if(a[i] != 0) {
        std::cout << (10 - a[i]);
    }
}
```

Bonus: Try not to use `using namespace std;` as its a bad practice. Basically what it does is, it takes the whole `std` namespace and dumps it into the global namespace. If its for competitive programming and time is limited, then it would be okay but for general programming, avoid it.